# I changed the mac address of my router to attempt to a get a new i.p addres, but. Now only one device gets internet

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, mac-address

I first unplugged my modem, then plugged in a different router. I got a new ip assigned. I then connected my computer to the original router and then changed the mac address of that router to the mac address of the 2nd one, unplugged my modem switched the ethernet back to the original router with the new mac address set. However some websites did not work. The router states the ethernet cable is not plugged in. So factory reset the router (thus changing the mac address back to its original) however the router is sending internet over Lan to my single computer but not to other devices, it also claims that the ethernet is still not connected.

I tried other cables.
Tried resets and power cycling

Not sure what else to think other than my isp restricting my modem in some capacity

Comment: Do the Web Sites you use track device MAC address and IP?  I have never needed to change my router's MAC address.

Comment: are either router ISP-provided? are they Internet-only routers or do either of them have have VOIP (phone) features as well? ISPs use complicated (usually custom) approaches to service codes to identify legit subscribers and set their entitlement, etc, so its conceivable that those mechanisms have been broken by your change. your ISP definitely controls your modem to ensure that only paying customers can connect to their network

Comment: Did you restore the configuration of the modem to it's original working configuration after you performed a reset?  I wish you came to us before you attempted your exercise we could have told you it wouldn't work the way you thought it would.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (1)  I changed the mac address, in order to get a new ip assigned from the dhcp (b) routers are my equipment and no voip features are available on the router (netgear nighthawk, not enterprise like cisco) (3)

Comment: So at this point, I'd recommend plugging your PC directly into the modem, and reboot everything, to see if you PC pulls an IP. Be assured, i am loathe to suggest this, but at this point you are not even sure the modem is able to connect to the ISP for service. if you get an IP and internet service,, then the modem is fine and you need to troubleshoot the router. shut down quickly once you have determined if it worked (its not safe). if it doesn't you need to call you ISP, as only they can fix their own equipment. Just tell them it just stopped working or something.